# Lambda nodeJS 4.3 not finishing/executing success callback

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda

Despite running the log statement immediately above it, my call to `callback(null)` isn't working. Even tried wrapping it in a try catch block but got nothing.

For reference, here's the full function:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var request = require('request');

//noinspection AnonymousFunctionJS
/**
 *
 * @param event - from Lambda
 * @param context - from Lambda
 * @param callback - from Lambda
 */
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var AUTOPILOT_API_KEY = getKey(event.stage, 'AUTOPILOT_API_KEY');
    var AUTOPILOT_JOURNEY_ID = getKey(event.stage, 'AUTOPILOT_JOURNEY_ID');
    activate();

    function activate () {
        console.log('event:', event);

        if (validPayload(event, context)) {
            addDefaultPresets(event.uid);
            addToAutopilot(event.user, event.uid);
        }
    }

    /**
     * checks that the necessary payload has been received
     * if YES: returns true and allows process to continue
     * if NO: throws context.fail with useful error message(s)
     * operating under custom error code naming convention of
     * http code + 3 digit ULM error code
     * @param event - from Lambda
     * @param context - from Lambda
     * @returns {boolean} - whether the payload contains the required data
     */
    function validPayload (event, context) {
        return true; // REDACTED FOR BREVITY
    }

    /**
     * Adds the user to Autopilot as a contact and adds them
     * to the journey with trigger id 0001
     * @param {Object} user
     * @param {string} uid generate by Firebase as unique identifier of registered user
     */
    function addToAutopilot (user, uid) {

        // REDACTED FOR BREVITY

        request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api2.autopilothq.com/v1/trigger/' + AUTOPILOT_JOURNEY_ID + '/contact',
            headers: {
                'autopilotapikey': AUTOPILOT_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            //noinspection MagicNumberJS
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                errorResponse.status = response.statusCode;
                errorResponse.error = {
                    errorMessage: error,
                    user: event.user,
                    response: response,
                    body: body
                };
                console.log('should throw ERROR callback');
                context.fail(JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
            } else {
                console.log('should throw SUCCESS callback');
                console.log(JSON.stringify({
                    status: response.statusCode,
                    message: "User successfully added to Autopilot account & journey"
                }));

                callback(null);
            }
            console.log('Finished addToAutopilot()');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adds a collection of presets the the account of the new user
     * @param uid {String} - Firebase UID
     */
    function addDefaultPresets (uid) {
        // REDACTED FOR BREVITY

        var presets = ref.child('users').child(uid).child('presets');

        console.log('Starting addDefaultPresets()');

        activate();

        function activate () {
            console.info('activating...');
            // for each field
            fields.forEach(function (field) {
                // iterate over each preset
                presetData[field].forEach(function (label) {
                    // and add to firebase db via addDefaultPreset() if unique
                    presetIsUnique(field, label);
                })
            });

            console.log('Finished addDefaultPresets()');
        }

        function presetIsUnique (field, label) {
            presets.child(field).orderByChild('label')
                .equalTo(label)
                .once('value', function (snapshot) {
                    var val = snapshot.val();
                    if (!val) {
                        addDefaultPreset(field, label);
                    } else {
                        console.error('already exists', field, label);
                    }
                });
        }

        function addDefaultPreset (field, label) {
            //noinspection MagicNumberJS
            presets.child(field).push().set({
                creator: 'default',
                dateAdded: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                label: label
            }, setCallback);
        }

        function setCallback (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.info('added preset');
            }
        }
    }

    function getKey (stage, keyId) {
        var keys = {
            AUTOPILOT_API_KEY: {
                staging: 'dev123',
                prod: 'prod123'
            },
            AUTOPILOT_JOURNEY_ID: {
                staging: 'XXX',
                product: 'XXXX'
            },
            FIREBASE_URL: {
                staging: 'https://staging.firebaseio.com/',
                prod: 'https://prod.firebaseio.com/'
            }
        };

        if (stage === 'prod') {
            return keys[keyId][stage];
        } else {
            return keys[keyId]['staging'];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean it is 'not working'?  What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?
Also, I notice you are using ```context.fail(JSON.stringify(errorResponse));```, this function is not available in the nodejs4.3 environment, you should be executing the calback with an error instead (```callback(error)```)

Comment: @JonathanSeed when I say 'not working' the function stays running until it times out and then returns the error message saying it timed out. 

It completes the task, but it runs way longer than it should which costs money and throws misleading errors.

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting... I have an idea, but it could be a red herring.  By default, lambda waits until the event loop is empty before freezing the process.  Could there be something in the event loop causing the function to continue?  You can test this by setting ```context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;```. This will cause lambda to freeze the process soon after the callback is called even if there is events in the event loop

Comment: @JonathanSeed I bet you're onto something. Firebase is probably keeping a connection open. I'll try this out and report back. Might also explicitly kill the Firebase ref in the callback.

Comment: @JonathanSeed it resolved the issue! Tried a few things with Firebase to clear the event loop / open connections when it finished its work but no luck. Is there a way to debug what active in the event loop via a log statement or anything?

Comment: I don't know of a way unfortunately.  If there is no real way to close a firebase connection I think using the context variable may be your best approach.  Taking a quick look it seems there is a goOffline() method, but I'm not sure if this will close the connection in a way that clears the event loop.

Comment: @JonathanSeed - I tried the goOffline but it didn't clear the event loop. Your suggestion to ignore event loop state fixes the issue and both functions are callback based so it's all good.

If you submit that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like firebase is keeping something in the event loop.  By default, lambda waits until the event loop is empty before terminating.  You can set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` to tell lambda to terminate the function soon after the callback is called, even if there is still items in the event loop.

Comment: This seems to be Firebase related. Would be great to have Firebase devs to look and advise.

Comment: I would suggest updating the correct answer to @temkin's below - `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` freezes the process, but it could be 'reused' if lamda chooses too, and who knows what state the event queue would be in then. If your intention was to cleanly exit the function, it almost certainly isn't what you want. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

Comment: Sorry, this was 18 months and several projects ago. It's all been cleared from my cache long ago :(.

Answer (score 3):

After hours and hours of debugging here is something that worked for me:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);

...
...
...

app.delete().then(function(){
   var response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
         message: 'Success'
      }),
   };
   callback(null, response);
});
```

You can read more about `delete` in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#delete):

> Make the given App unusable and free the resources of all associated
>   services.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Where would I place the app.delete part?